# Optimal renders of the same scene from multiple cameras

Tags: python, rendering, 3d-view, optimization

I am using Cycles with OptiX to render a lot of different camera angles of the same scene.

Using code like:

```
for camera in cameras:
  # Set camera location to x,y,z etc

  # Render the scene
  bpy.ops.render.render()
```

Works for me, but I have an issue that each render re-initializes the OptiX renderer and re uploads all the data. In my case this is a significant amount of data. I have found that setting a multi camera works for this:

```
bFirstCamera = True
for camera in cameras:
  cameraPosition = camera.position

  # Create the camera object
  camObj = bpy.data.objects.new("Camera_" + camera.name, camData)
  camObj.location = (cameraPosition[0], cameraPosition[1], cameraPosition[2])
  bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(camObj)

  # Get the first render view and override it
  renderView = bpy.context.scene.render.views[0]
  if bFirstCamera == False:
      renderView = bpy.context.scene.render.views.new(camera.name)
  else:
      bpy.context.scene.camera = camObj    

  # Set the camera in the render view
  renderView.name          = camera.name
  renderView.camera_suffix = camera.name
  renderView.file_suffix   = camera.name
  renderView.use = True

  bFirstCamera = False

# Render the scene with all cameras at once
bpy.ops.render.render()
```

This also works and is much faster than doing them one by one.
However, the compositing stage does not run until all the cameras are rendered, which uses a lot of memory (there are a lot of views) and another image process (outside of Blender) that is waiting on the results cannot start processing the images until all of them are done.

Is there a way I can:

- Flag "do compositing after each render view"?
- Or, Keep optiX scene in memory between renders if no change?
- Or, Some other Blender render view setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I have found the setting I need:

**Render Properties -> Performance -> Final Render -> [Persistent Data](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/render/cycles/render_settings/performance.html?highlight=persistent#final-render)**

or the python

```py
bpy.context.scene.render.use_persistent_data = True
```

The Persistent Data feature is new in Blender 2.93 (see [release notes](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/2-93/)).