# Rendering multi-view directly to disk instead of RAM

Tags: cycles-render-engine, memory-management, stereoscopy

I've set up a **Stereoscopy -> Multi-View** rendering to render hundreds of cameras with a Python script.

Multi-view renders the cameras much faster than looping over `bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=1)` because it loads the model / start Cycles only once. I'm using flat shading with 0 bounces so loading the inputs takes longer than actually rendering a camera from it.

However, this will render all cameras into RAM, and write them to disk at the end, making the computer run out of memory quickly.

If found [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227039/optimal-renders-of-the-same-scene-from-multiple-cameras/) which works around the problem, avoiding the repeated model load using the **Persistent Data** option. That allows to use non-Multi-View at good performance. However, I would still like to know if a Multi-View solution is possible.

**Is it possible to set up Blender such that the multi-view cameras will be rendered to disk instead of RAM?**

---

[image]